# Install wx python in virtualenv

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, wxpython

I have system running UbuntuMate 16.04

I have python 2.7 installed and I am running python 3.5 in a virtualenv

In both, wx.version() returns

```
3.0.2.0 gtk2 (classic)
```

I want to use wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl and I cannot import the wx.adv module

I assume that I need to upgrade to wx Phoenix from classic. Unfortunately, I just cannot understand how to do this. I have followed the installation instruction from [here](https://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython), using the following command in the virtualenv

```
 pip install -U \
      -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk2/ubuntu-16.04 \
   wxPython
```

This gives the following error:

```
 Found existing installation: wxPython 3.0.2.0
 Cannot uninstall 'wxPython'. 
 It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot 
 accurately determine which files belong to it which would 
 lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

I have tried to discover ways of upgrading wxPython, but it seems to be a topic on which the web is silent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this I opened caja as su and renamed

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packges/wx-3.0-gtk2
```

I was then able to run the command

```
sudo pip install -U \
  -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk2/ubuntu-16.04 \
wxPython
```

Of course this implements a new version of wxPython globally and not just in my virtualenv, but HeyHo